# Pandas groupby - how to see distribution of values in a mean

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, trading

The code below downloads daily prices for Apple (AAPL) back to 1980.

I wanted to see the average gain in price for the next 10 days by day of year. eg:- October 20th averages 2% gain historically over the next 10 days.

I converted each date to a unique identifier ("uniqdttm") and then .groupby to group all pricegains by this identifier, and use a .mean() to see the average of all price gains for each date.

```
import yFinance as yf

tick = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
df = tick.history(period="max", interval="1d", prepost=False, auto_adjust=True, back_adjust=False, actions=False)

nmm = "FutureGainDays-10"
df["gaintmp"] = df["Close"].pct_change(periods=10).fillna(0).mul(100)
df[nmm] = df["gaintmp"].shift(-10)        # Shift back x days to see what the gain would have been

df["uniqdt"] = df.index.strftime('%b-%d')
df["tmpdate"] = "1972-"+df.index.strftime('%m-%d')          # 1972 is a leap year needed for Feb29!
df["uniqdttm"] = pd.to_datetime(df["tmpdate"], format="%Y-%m-%d")

aggs = df.groupby("uniqdttm")[nmm].agg(['mean']).round(3)
print(aggs)
```

Output:

```
             mean
uniqdttm         
1972-01-02  0.960
1972-01-03  2.855
1972-01-04  0.905
1972-01-05  1.289
1972-01-06  1.601
...           ...
1972-12-27  3.995
1972-12-28  2.732
1972-12-29  4.588
1972-12-30  4.359
1972-12-31  2.108
```

Where I am confused is how to see where the distribution of the mean lies in the data.

An example:

For date x: 5 price gains of:

```
-4
-6
+10
-2
+7
```

give an average gain of +5

But trading this would be emotionally very difficult. 3 years of losses and 2 years of big gains.

5 price gains of +1, +2, -1, +1, +1 would give an average of +4 (which is less than +5 above) but is much easier to trade.

What statistical measure would give a better representation of how many positives are present in the samples - and how do I see this in the dataframe groupby output?

**EDIT**:
Is it also possible to see all values that contributed to the mean in the groupby output sorted smallest to largest, eg:

```
             mean
uniqdttm         
1972-01-02  5.0  -6 -4 -2 7 10
```

Comment: Not sure what your target output is. From my limited understanding of statistics, the statistical measure you are looking for is Skewness or Kurtosis.

Comment: I am only responding to your final request: how to see all the values (sorted) that contributed to the mean. You can try this: `aggs = df.groupby("uniqdttm")[nmm].agg(['mean', sorted]).round(3)`